# How to write Criteria query for parent rows when all children must match the filtering criteria in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, java-8, criteria

I am having a situation where I have child entity under a parent entity, and I need to get the list of parents while child entities matches  certain criteria. Let me post the entities

```
class ParentEntity{
      @Filed("name")
      @JsonProperty("name")
      String name;
      @Filed("address")
      @JsonProperty("address")
      String address;
      List<ChildEntity> childEntity;
  ..................

 class ChildEntity{
  @Filed("price")
  @JsonProperty("price")
  String price;
  @Filed("cft")
  @JsonProperty("cft")
  String cft;
  @Filed("kpc")
  @JsonProperty("kpc")
  List<String> itemKpc;
```

Now i am trying to get the list of parent object where the any item in the child object is missing , to get that i am trying to write a criteria query. Below is my criteria

```
  Query query = new Query();
  List<Criteria> criteria = ArrayList<>();
  criteria.add(Criteria.where(Constants.NAME).is(false));
  criteria.add(Criteria.where(Constants.ADDRESS).is(false));
  .........How to add the criteria to check if any of the child item is empty
```

Here i am executing the criteria Query

```
  List<ParentEntity> parentListObject;
  parentListObject = mongoTemplate.find(query,ParentEntity.class);
```

How to write the Criteria for the child entities where at least one item is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of framework getting in your way.  First, understand what the database needs, then try to fit the framework.

Here are some raw records and a query that addresses your question...

**Example test data:**

```
db.test.insertMany([
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address": "1234 Main Street",
  "childEntities": [
    {
      "price": 123.45,
      "cft": "abc123",
      "kpc": [
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Wilma Flintstone",
  "address": "534 Rockaway Blvd.",
  "childEntities": [
    {
      "price": 44.76,
      "kpc": [
        "xxx",
        "yyy",
        "zzz"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
])
```

Notice Wilma Flintstone has no childEntities cft value?

**Query to find missing cft child value:**

db.test.find({"childEntities.cft" : null})

**Results:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("614a3ba438827aab97353d73"), "name" : "Wilma Flintstone", "address" : "534 Rockaway Blvd.", "childEntities" : [ { "price" : 44.76, "kpc" : [ "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" ] } ] }
```

Comment: actually i am looking for the way to write a  criteria for it

Comment: @Mandrek - OK, well, perhaps my example will help show you what the database needs, and from this you can adapt the criteria.  Your example shows a criteria filter where you are trying to find records having the name and address fields equal to the boolean value of false.  My example shows a filter where a field is null.  Also your example is filtering parent records, but your post says you want to filter on child records.